# Pythonic way of copying a dict without distinct attribute

Tags: python

In ECMAScript6 you can use the spread operator to destructure an object like this

```
const {a, ...rest} = obj;
```

Which does a shallow copy of `obj` to `rest` without attribute `a`.

Is there a clean way of doing the same in python?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python dict literals can use the unpacking operator, like `{ **obj, 'a': 3 }` to make a shallow copy overriding some particular properties, but there is no special syntax to omit a property from the unpacking. Also, while python can destructure sequences and nested sequences, you cannot use a dictionary pattern on the left-hand-side of an destructuring assignment.

However, it is possible to do this a bit more verbosely using a dict comprehension:

```py
rest = { k: v for k, v in obj.items() if k != 'a' }
```

But for readability, two lines is probably better:

```py
rest = dict(obj)
rest.pop('a', None)
```

Or if you expect the key `'a'` to always appear in the original dictionary, and you'd like a `KeyError` when it's missing, you can use `del`:

```py
rest = dict(obj)
del rest['a']
```

Comment: Upvote for making it a Python problem I can understand :-). I think the ECMAScript version won't crash if `a` doesn't exist. If that can happen, might want to do `rest.pop('a', None)` to be safe.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Good call, I've edited. The version with `del` might be preferable to avoid failing silently when the key `'a'` is expected to exist, so I've left both versions.

Comment: In between, there's `rest = dict(t for t in obj.items() if t[0] != 'a')`. Also, since you don't care about `a`, you can always add an explicit key `a`, overwriting whatever you were going to drop anyway. `rest=dict(obj, a=None); rest.pop('a')`

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't call it "clean", but we can (ab)use the function keyword parameter mechanism:

```
>>> obj = {'b': 2, 'a': 1, 'c': 3}
>>> (lambda a=None, **rest: rest)(**obj)
{'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Or if the goal was to assign to two variables `a` and `rest` (I'm not sure since I don't do ECMAScript):

```
obj = {'b': 2, 'a': 1, 'c': 3}
a, rest = (lambda a=None, **rest: (a, rest))(**obj)

print('a:   ', a)
print('rest:', rest)
```

Output:

```
a:    1
rest: {'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

An possible answer that works, but may not be the prettiest is:

```py
new_dict= rest.copy()  # create copy to delete keys
try:
    del new_dict["a"]
except KeyError:
    print("The key 'a' was not found.")
```